# What is the api to clear selection on a af:table?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, trinidad

I have a two ADF faces table say `A` and `B` and their  `rowSelection` property is  is set to "`single`". Now the requirement is when one row is selected from `A` , it should clear out all selections from `B` and vice versa . So I have registered `selectionListeners` on both the tables and the code that gets executed inside that method is doing the following for the table that has not been selected :

```
tablenNotSelected.setSelectedRowKeys(null);
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to setup the partial triggers on the table, or possibly the surrounding container, to actually force a screen update.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the selected row keys to null. Instead use the `getSelectedRowKeys().RemoveAll();` API.

To get the other table refreshed do the following.

```
table_1_selectionListener() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(T2);
}
```

Similar for table 2 listener

Answer (score 0):

```
public void clearTableSelection(RichTable table) {
    table.getSelectedRowKeys().clear();
    RowKeySetAttributeChange rks = new RowKeySetAttributeChange(table.getClientId(), "selectedRowKeys", new RowKeySetImpl());
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getChangeManager().addComponentChange(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),table, rks);
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(table);
}
```

Comment: Hi, your code is badly formatted, contains no textual explanation to why this is a solution, contains no info on the version this works on (version in the question is over 8 years old, are you using the same?) so effectively your answer is not the best