# how to disable auto selection in oracle adf tables?

Tags: oracle-adf

in oracle adf when we drop a table from Data Controls to a jsf page,and when we run project a row of table is pre_selected. what should I do that at first time load of the page no rows is selected?
I use jdeveloper 11g R2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482629/what-is-the-api-to-clear-selection-on-a-aftable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting selectedRowKeys attribute in the table properties:

```
<af:table value="#{bindings.View1.collectionModel}" 
 ...
     selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.View1.collectionModel.selectedRow}">
```

If you have a master/child relationship, set refresh condition of child to "ifNeeded".

Once user selects rows and triggers an event, in a backing bean get a handle to the table (various ways to do this), then you can get selected rows using:

```
Iterator tableIterator = tableHandle.getSeletedRowKeys().Iterator();
if (tableIterator.hasNext()) {
    ...do stuff
```

Once you've processed the selection(s), you can clear the selection and add partial target to show the table again without selection. First refresh the table iterator, then clear the selected keys:

```
if (tableHandle.getSelectedRowKeys() != null) {
    tableHandle.getSelectedRowKeys().clear();
}
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(tableHandle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this, it might help you
to disable rowSelection permanently you can set table rowSelection to none and remove it's selection listener and selected rowkey
See this -http://amit-adf-work.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-disable-adf-default-row.html
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use property **rowSelection="none"** for af:table to disable row selection.

-Vinoth

Comment: The question references auto selection, not disabling selection entirely (e.g. not disabling manual selection).